# Nesting UICollectionViews - how should I handle the data from core data?

Tags: ios, core-data, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I need to add scrolling in both directions for my `UICollectionView` - Much like netflix app does. I know that I can add another `UICollectionView` in to a single-column `UICollectionViewCell` object, but my question is what is the best way to pass the data for each section in to the nested `UICollectionView`?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data structure, the easiest way might be to use two separate `NSFetchedResultsController`s.